# Adding Similar Elements

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Please bear with me my maths is very rusty.

If we have $x^2 + x^2$ this should be $2x^2$ meaning if powers are the same we can do the addition.

The question I have is how is $2^{x+1} + 2^{x+1} = 2.2^{x+1}$
then they apply the exponent rule and the final result is $2^{x+2}$.

The exponent rule makes sense to me since they are now multiplying and $2^1 * 2^{x+1}$ but why isnt $2^{x+1} + 2^{x+1} = 4^{x+1}$
since $4^{x+1} = 2.2^{x+1}$ but $4^{x+1} \neq2^{x+2} $

Comment: $a^n + b^n \neq (a+b)^n$.  Further $a^n+b^n\neq (ab)^n$.  Finally, $a\cdot (b^n)\neq (a\cdot b)^n$.  I'm not sure which of these three rules you thought it would be, but simply it doesn't work that way.  Follow the rules of associativity, distributivity, and exponent laws.  The derivation $2^{x+1}+2^{x+1}=(1+1)2^{x+1}=2\cdot 2^{x+1}=2^1\cdot 2^{x+1}=2^{x+2}$ is correct.  Yours somehow made a step which was untrue.  $4^{x+1}\neq 2\cdot 2^{x+1}$

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is not uncommon. What you've done is ignore the invisible brackets.

When you break down the exponent, you really have $$4^{x+1}=(2×2)^{x+1}=2^{x+1}×2^{x+1}\neq 2×2^{x+1}$$

with the final part as you observed. This is because the exponent applies to the entire base, and in order to maintain the same expression, you have to keep the factors of that base together as an object. In mathematics, of course, that means putting in a pair of brackets; they weren't written originally because we can already see $4$ is a single object.